# Accessing missing BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 OpenCV function

Tags: java, opencv

I've been using BackgroundSubtractorMOG so far and noticed the online demos of people using MOG2 show better results. IS there any way to access this function on Desktop Java despite the fact that the binding are not available?

Comment: What version are you using? The bindings are there in 2.4.10.